# Errors importing large CSV file into MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm importing a large CSV file into MySQL. The file has a lot of columns, and I'm trying to set the datatypes for the fields in MySQL.

But as I imported the file I realize that some of the values that I thought would be there were absent. And were being imported into MySQL as empty strings ('').

For instance, I'm getting these errors:

```
MySQL Exception: 1366 (HY000): Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'PricingPlanId' at row 1
MySQL Exception: 1366 (HY000): Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'SubscriptionId' at row 1
MySQL Exception: 1366 (HY000): Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'LinkedAccountId' at row 1
MySQL Exception: 1366 (HY000): Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'InvoiceId' at row 1
```

...inserting data in my table when the CSV has blank lines for those rows. This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS billing_info (
    `ID` INT  AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `InvoiceId` INT,
    `LinkedAccountId` BIGINT,
    `SubscriptionId` INT,
    `PricingPlanId` INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

I'm just presenting the columns that were producing errors in this question.

How can I account for this variability of datatypes as I'm inserting the data into MySQL.

Comment: Tidy up the csv file or create work table where all fields varchar load to that and tidy up before migrating to final table or use load data infile and load everything to variables which you can then manipulate before load to target.

Comment: OK I guess that may be the only way. However the CSV file is over 4GB and almost 10 million rows. So there's no way to open the file in excel. Any idea how I can open a file this large?

Comment: 'open a file this large' - do i take it from this statement that you don't have vba/vba skills. BTW I gave 2 other options are they not options for you?

Comment: A good text editor might be able to cope with it. But tidying it up using some code might be a good idea

Comment: have you tried --ignore-lines=1 to ignore the first line für mysqlimport, if the rest seems to be in order

Comment: I use next(csv_reader) in python to skip the header row.

Comment: Also, yeah maybe tidying it up via python might be a good idea. I'll see if I can get that done.

Comment: Yeah sorry I didn't read you correctly about tidying it up via a 'work' table with all varchars and then migrating it to it's correct table. That does sound like a good way to do that!